# Adding Methods to String In a Namespace

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm defining some new methods on `String`. I need to be sure these methods do not conflict with methods defined in other libraries (for reference, I created an inflector and then added `pluralize` and `singularize` onto `String`).

My first thought was to wrap the new stuff in a module like so:

```
module MM
  class String
    def rev
      self.split('').reverse.join('')
    end
  end
end

class Test
  include MM

  def me(s)
    s.rev
  end
end

puts Test.new.me('this is a test')
```

but of course this doesn't work. `String#rev` remains undefined. What I really have in my code is a module `MM` and everything except the built-in type extensions is wrapped in `MM`. My goal is to have `String` have methods like `rev`, `singularize` and `pluralize` but only inside that module, `MM`.

This seems like it ought to be doable. But somehow I'm missing the secret incantation that will make it so.

If anyone can offer some suggestions it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not totally sure I understand; you want to extend String only within your own class?

Comment: Only within my own module. I just need to avoid these stepping on other implementations and vice versa. I know I can rename them to solve the problem but this seems like what namespaces were designed for.

Comment: It's what "concerns" were designed for; dynamically defining/undefining methods inside a class is something a bit different. If you want to define the methods in a module and put them into String that's different than only having those methods available within a specific scope.

Comment: I think Ruby 2.0 introduced some new monkey-patching features that (might) help with these sorts of things.

Comment: Below ruby 2.0, you can only put the monkey patch in global space, which will affects all classes (does not meet your requirement); in ruby 2.0, you can use `refinement` showing in the answer below, which is your only choice

Comment: Refinement, that's what I meant--I said concerns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for "refinements". They are an experimental feature in Ruby 2.0, so you might be out of luck if you're not using 2.0. I haven't used them myself yet, but your example is almost the canonical use case for refinements. Use the `refine` and `using` keywords to get the behavior you want:

```
module MM
  refine class String
    def rev
      self.split('').reverse.join('')
    end
  end
end

class Test
  using MM

  def me(s)
    s.rev
  end
end

puts Test.new.me('this is a test')
```

Comment: BTW: This doesn't work. I only just discovered this myself a couple of minutes ago while writing pretty much exactly what you wrote above ;-) It *did* work until very recently, but the specification for Refinements was changed shortly before the release of 2.0.0-p0. In particular, `using` is defined as a private singleton method of the top-level `main` object, which means it is *only* available in top-level scope. Thus, Refinements *always* apply to the *entire* file and *all* modules and classes defined within (but only after the call to `using`, of course).

Comment: Calling `using` within a class or module declaration and having the Refinement only apply within that scope *did* work until recently, and probably *will* work in the future, but for the release version of Ruby 2.0, it is disabled. Unfortunately, all the blog posts, and indeed my own answers on StackOverflow show exactly that usage.

Comment: Oh, snap. I'm stuck on 1.9 for now. I think I'll use the brute force method of naming my methods mm_singularize or mm_pluralize for right now. It's a language issue (IMO) -- particularly when multiple libraries (gems) are likely to need/implement similar methods but are unwilling to introduce a dependency on, say, ActiveSupport.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the additional info, Jörg. I agree it's a language issue, Steve. Hopefully refinements become a stable feature in the future. I believe it would be the first time a major language addresses this issue out of the box. Smalltalk (which kinda has open classes like Ruby) has the same problem. There was work in the Smalltalk world on a concept similar to refinements, called "classboxes", but I don't think it went anywhere.

Comment: Actually, I think Classboxes originated in Java. Smalltalk has Selector Namespaces, which were also considered for Ruby.

Comment: This is getting way off-topic, but many years ago I worked with Alex Bergel when he was working on classboxes. They were certainly first prototyped in Smalltalk (way easier to do than in Java). Proposing/implementing a Java version later may have been a strategic decision because it was easier to get a Java paper into OOPSLA at the time ...

Comment: Ah, I forgot about PDD (Paper-Driven Development) ;-) Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 2):

Lacking refinements, you could extend individual string objects:

```
module StringHelper
  def rev
    self.split('').reverse.join('')
  end
end

class Test
  def me(s)
    s.extend(StringHelper).rev
  end
end
```

Or subclass String:

```
class StringPlus < String
  def rev
    self.split('').reverse.join('')
  end
  def self.[](s)
    new(s)
  end
end

class Test
  def me(s)
    StringPlus[s].rev
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It was one of the directions I was looking at. The problem I'm facing is that these objects can be thrown at me by a user and the type is unknown until sussed out by a `case` statement -- my code is in a Gem. Explicitly creating a `StringPlus` for everything that might be a string seems like a code smell. I think simply renaming my particular extensions would leave me feeling less "dirty," if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is another way you can keep your string class separated. Until you add require it will be free from everything.

```
#my_string.rb
class String
  def rev
      self.split('').reverse.join('')
   end
end

#test.rb
class Test
  require 'F:\on going\New Site\Ruby\my_string.rb' # Assuming both these files are in the same folder


  def me(s)
    s.rev
  end
end


puts Test.new.me('this is a test')
```

Comment: gives `NoMethodError: undefined method 'rev' for "this is a test":String`

Comment: That's because `rev` is not being added to `String`'s methods. Your method 'm' works because it is simply an instance method on class `Test`. I'm wanting `s.rev` to work.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround in the absence of refinements, I found that this kind of thing works:

```
# class String
#   def rev
#     puts "rev: #{self}"
#   end
# end

class String
  unless String.instance_methods.include?(:rev)
    def rev
      self.split('').reverse.join('')
    end
  end
end

class Test
  def me(s)
    s.rev
  end
end

puts Test.new.me('this is a test')
```

If you uncomment the earlier definition of `rev` it will be honored and not overridden. This is a bit hacky and relies on the order in which files load, but it does work if the load order is controlled.